# Best way to store a single variable in AWS Lambda Python Variable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that connects to a service. This service limits the number of times I can connect, so I want to keep the connection open as long as possible.

`connection = Connection()`

Is there way to maintain/keep that connection variable between function calls?

I don't think Parameter store would work because its not one of its supported variable types and I don't think DynamoDB supports that type either. Currently, I think I would have to use an ec2 instance, but that seems expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the "connection" outside of the handler, the execution environment is (typically) re-used.  You can also store some variables in /tmp, but you have to check and initialize as needed to handle cold starts.

Look as the Lambda best practices for more details.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. I'll check out both solutions you mentioned